# Strtok returning extra data at end of line

Tags: c++, string, char, strtok

I have been messing with this code for hours upon hours and am looking for some advice. I am using strtok to get words from a string, but I keep getting extra data at the end of each line. I have the following code:

```
cout << "\n\n6. Load File:\n";
        getline(cin, inFile);
        inFile = path + inFile;
        myfile.open(inFile.c_str());
            while (myfile.is_open() == false)   //check to make sure file exists
            {
                cout << "\nPlease enter in a valid file name: ";
                getline(cin,inFile);
                inFile = path + inFile;
                myfile.open(inFile.c_str());
            }
                getline (myfile,line);
                while ( myfile.good() )     //while the file is running, run below code
                {
                    getline (myfile,line);
                    //cout << line;
                    char str[line.length()];
                    char * pch;
                    for (int i=0;i<line.size();i++) { //creates a char array from characters
                        str[i]=line[i];
                    }
                    pch = strtok(str," ,-!?\r\t\f\v\n\0|/\\_"); //eliminates whitespace,etc in char array
                    while (pch != NULL)
                    {
                        printf ("%s\n",pch);
                        pch = strtok (NULL, " ,-!?\r\t\f\v\n\0|/\\_");  //grabs next word
                    }

                }
        myfile.close();
```

Now this code gives me my desired word output, but with random crazy values from memory at the end of each line. See below: 
Load File:
cars1.txt
Jalopy
Blue
3402.99**\244\363P**
Rustbucket
Brown
44.99**P**
Lemon
Yellow
4226.99**99P**

Please help and many thanks!

Comment: In addition to the problem where you're not terminating the string you're using with `strtok()`, are you supposed to skip the first line of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `C`, strings have to have a `NUL` (0) at the end. You need to add that.

(This also means that the `\0` in your token string is considered the end of that string, and the following characters will be ignored. That will make this conform to your comment about whitespace, but it might not be what you really want.)

Simplest solution: use `strdup` to duplicate your string.

```
char* tmp_copy = strdup(line.c_str());
for (char* pch = strtok(tmp_copy," ,-!?\r\t\f\v\n\0|/\\_");
     pch;
     pch = strtok (NULL, " ,-!?\r\t\f\v\n\0|/\\_")) {
   printf ("%s\n",pch);
}
free(tmp_copy);
```

Better solution: Use [boost::tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/tokenizer/).

Comment: I did this, but now it is only grabbing the first word of each line

Comment: @user1828780: when you say "I did this", I suppose you don't actually mean that you did *this* (cut and paste from the answer): http://liveworkspace.org/code/Fai1V%240 because that seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to null-terminate `str`.  You are copying `line` to `str` one character at a time, but not the terminating null.

Try this:

```
char str[line.length()+1];
char * pch;
for (int i=0;i<line.size();i++) {
    str[i]=line[i];
}
str[line.size()+1] = '\0';     // null terminator
```

Or simpler, just initialize `str`:

```
char str[line.length()+1] = {};  // initialize to all nulls
char * pch;
for (int i=0;i<line.size();i++) {
    str[i]=line[i];
}
```

Comment: Buffer overrun. You need to also allocate space for the `0`.